# How to create new date and insert as index in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Im predicting total sales for next month and set the date as index in dataframe. How do I calculate new upcoming month as index and put it in a new row in the same dataframe?

I use this code below to get a new date from previous date:

```
from datetime import timedelta

last_date = df.iloc[[-1]].index
last_date = last_date + timedelta(days=30)

df= df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=[last_date]))

df.tail()
```

But, the output seemed not correct. Im expecting the result will be like below for the new upcoming index:

> 2017-07-30

But, instead, the output is like this:

> (2017-07-30 00:00:00,)

How can I remove the time and also the unnecessary symbol there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, remove `[]` for avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=last_date))
```

**Sample**:

```
from datetime import timedelta

rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3)}, index=rng)  

last_date = df.iloc[[-1]].index
last_date = last_date + timedelta(days=30)


df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=last_date))
print (df)
              a
2017-04-03  0.0
2017-04-04  1.0
2017-04-05  2.0
2017-05-05  NaN
```

---

Test index of DataFrame with `[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[last_date])
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('2017-05-05',)],
           )
```